# Symfony Bundle for Views

Tags: symfony, bundle, soa

In our application when a view is rendered, it doesn't have the data in it when it's returned to the user.

The page (which acts like a template only), uses javascript (angularjs) to fetch the json data. Usually calling the same controller.

That is, when the URL is accessed an html is requested. The response is the html template. Then when it's called with json format requested. It returns the json data that is used to populate the page.

```
http://example.com/products        // requested as html returns html page
http://example.com/products.json   // requested with content-type:application/json will 
                                      return the json data
```

controller looks like..

```
class ProductController {

   public function indexAction() {
      if (html request) {
         render template
      }

      else do processing to return json response
   }
}
```

My question is.. Should we consider creating a separate bundle whose task if to generate the views alone?

Or probably create a different application altogether for the views..

Comment: You can set `format` in Your routing and if You call `products.json` You will get json output (header)

Comment: Do you pass the proper data to the view from your controller? Also as @skowron-line mentioned on your else section you need to set the response header as `Content-Type : application/json`

Comment: the routing and how the request is formatted is not actually my issue.. if you notice the controller it currently does two task: return the html template on an html request; and return the json data (used to populate the template) on a json request..  my question was would it be rather more efficient to separate these tasks into separate bundles.. or even decouple it completely into separate applications (codebases).